# JQuery hide collapsable menu clicking anywhere else - blur -

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Setting this JQuery function does not work properly. Sometimes If I click on the elements nothing happens and it's triggered the function that hides the collapsable menu if clicking anywhere on the document, without redirecting to the correct href's. Any better methods?

HTML

```
    <div>
      <button id="bottone" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav " aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about_me">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contacts.php">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $("#bottone").blur(function (event) {
        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (screenWidth < 768) {
          $("#navbarNav").collapse('hide');
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I use Bootstrap  4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use button blur , 
You can achieve it only with `$(document).on("click",function(e){ ... })`

this will toggle menu showing also allow redirect when link without anchor .

see below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(document).on("click",function(e){
    var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (screenWidth < 768) {
      $("#navbarNav").collapse('hide');
    }
 });

});
```

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
  <button id="bottone" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav " aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about_me">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-" href="/contacts.php">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```